# Second VGA monitor is not being detected

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor, intel-graphics, hdmi, vga

I have 2 Monitors 
Primary HDMI (Nvidia 1050Ti): Working perfectly fine.
Secondary VGA (Intel Motherboard): Blank.

sudo lshw -C display

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 630
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:132 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

lspci | grep VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
```

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

xrandr --listmonitors

```
Monitors: 1
 0: +*HDMI-0 1920/480x1080/270+0+0  HDMI-0
```

Comment: Are you sure that monitor is connected correctly? Can you hook it up to another computer to check if it works?

Comment: FWIW, `xrandr` output doesn't even mention VGA. Are you sure you use VGA connector or rather DisplayPort?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I have ubuntu on the same machine and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting Monitor 2 to the motherboard video port, connect it to  another port on the 1050 Ti, which has multiple ports.

Comment: this 1050ti has only one HDMI and 2 DP, My monitor doesn't have DP.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated graphics may not work if discrete exists.  As mentioned, plug both monitors into the nVidia card.

[While I've been down voted for my answer, I have several computer for which this is true.  Without specific mobo manufacturing part numbers, revision levels, BIOS version, and CPU specifics, it is entirely possible the integrated GPU on the Intel CPU is disabled.]

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Since you already reference another answer in your post for the "actual" solution, you may want to edit your answer to include some details on _why_ (i.e. under what circumstances) mixing of integrated and plug-in graphics cards can interfere to produce the problem described in the question; this could help others prevent such problems in the first place or give them advice on whether the solution presented here is applicable to their problem ...

Comment: both work perfectly on Ubuntu, and I have enabled integrated graphics from BIOS settings.